# django url rule not working

Tags: django-1.3

I'm a django newbie. Here is my problem.... My main urls.py has a rule for checking published section to published app, like this:

```
(r'^(published/)$', include('published.urls')),
```

My published app urls.py is like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('published.views',
# Examples:
(r'^$', 'index',),
(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'article'),
)
```

I'm trying to fetch a url like this

```
http://localhost:8000/published/2/
```

Problem is its showing a 404 error. Just to clarify my view is like this:

```
def article(request):
try:
    p = Published.objects.get(pk = id)
except Published.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
return render_to_response('published/inner.html', {'pubs': p}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try removing the `$` from the end of `r'^(published/)$'`. If it still does not work, try removing the `^` from the beginning of `r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$'`. Since `$` matches the end of a string, the regex fails to match when there is a character after the first `/`.